# Numpy TypeError when turning ndarray into structured array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I want to turn my `ndarray(670911L, 39L)` into a structured array using a view:

```
c = arr.view(dtype=[(n, ‘float64’) for n in names]).reshape(len(arr))
```

where names is a list of 39 strings. But I am getting a `TypeError: data type not understood`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: NumPy can be used for GIS but is not by my understanding a spatial library so I think this question would be better researched/asked at [so].

Comment: It is part of the arcpy.da module and its interface to NumPyArrayToFeatureClass.  The construction of the array to facilitate moving it back into ArcMap is not well covered and this provides needed information.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is in the encoding of the `names` list. The list consists of unicode strings `[u'something', u'more']` and that will not work.

Hence, the unicode needs to be changed:

```
names = [x.encode('UTF8') for x in names]
```

... and it works. ;-)

Comment: remember when working in python 3.x (which will be soon) within the arcmap environment, unicode is default.  See your other post, you can enforce unicode by declaring it in the first line of your script